# Trying to randomize where a name is inserted into a table using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I'm trying to accomplish is randomize elements of an array which contain column names. Then use those randomized columns names to insert a name into a table.

Here is the code I have and its causing a Internal Server Error.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM players";
$result3 = $con->query($sql3);

while ($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $num_bracket1 = $row3["num_bracket"];
    $name = $row3["name"];

    $y = 1;

    while ($y <= $num_bracket1) {
        shuffle($bracket_array);
        shuffle($player_array);

        $sql4 = "UPDATE brackets SET ".$player_array[0]."='".$name."' WHERE bracket_num='".$bracket_array[0]"'";
        $result4 = $con->query($sql4);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious infinite loop, you forgot to increment `$y` inside the `while` and it never ends.